# fill random area with color

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to fill any random area with color. I have several points with some coordinates(number of points > 2). (I should get points by mouse clicking -> random points). So to test filling with color I use some random points

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(200.0 / WIDTH, 300.0 / HEIGHT);
    glVertex2f(300.0 / WIDTH, 100.0 / HEIGHT);
    glVertex2f(500.0 / WIDTH, 400.0 / HEIGHT);
    glVertex2f(400.0 / WIDTH, 200.0 / HEIGHT);
glEnd();
```

But the result does not look like it supposed to be
[image]

I know that points should be in some specific order - but how to apply it to random points?

Comment: Following the coordinates, this figure is *exactly* what it is "supposed to". This is a folded rectangle; the two bottom "points" are two opposing corners, and the diagonal 'fold' is the top line. Given your input, it's hard to second-guess what you meant it to be. A swan? A spaceship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort all the vertices so that following the order you can draw a convex polygon. This is actually a topic in computational geometry: [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

A simple algorithm is that you first sort all the vertices with respect to x coordinate and then look for the topmost and bottom-most vertices for each x coordinate value. Then you can choose one leftmost vertex and go clockwise to one rightmost vertex (always choosing topmost vertices along the way), then go ahead and back to the initial vertex (always choosing bottom-most vertices).

Comment: You can also use the GLU tessellator utilities on most platforms that provide OpenGL. Before I implemented delaunay triangulation myself I used the GLU tessellator in a D3D project, it can be shoe-horned into a lot of non-OpenGL applications :)